# Workflow creates document approval task and triggers email alerts even after workflow has been deleted

Tags: workflow, email

We have SP2010 Environment. Our HR team activated document approval workflow on one of the library and since then it creates document approval task and triggers email alerts to few people to approve.

After some time workflow removed from that library but it kept sending email alerts.
Later on, even that document library was deleted to stop email alerts but Still it keeps sending email alerts. 
I have linked at bottom, picture of email alert for better idea.

The document location link comes in email alert is unavailable now as library has been deleted.

I can not see any alert set up for any person in Site Administration -> User alerts.

Can anyone please tell me how can I stop this email alerts?

Appreciate your help in advance.

[Picture of Email Alert](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-_pIXGQfR4GQ/TkM2Quu5BVI/AAAAAAAACN4/hd9Nl-INJTo/s800/Email%252520alert.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had UA environment setup based on live environment and Staging UA environment was triggering those task email.

Answer (score 1):

The email alert you are getting there is merely saying that your tasks are overdue - the task list on the site that had the workflow on it will need to be cleared to ensure that there are no old tasks. Deleting a workflow will not automatically clear out all the tasks that already existed. There should be a link to the task in the email you received, and from there you should be able to get to the tasks library, and delete everything that is no longer needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for quick reply. So if I will delete task list would it stop sending emails. I noticed there are no entries in that task list.

Comment: Yes - if you clear the task list, you'll no longer get reminder or expiry emails. You will have to change the view on the task list before you will be able to see the tasks - the default view will only show you tasks that are assigned to you. Try "All Items".

Comment: Hi Mike, default view for system created workflow task list is "all Items" with no entries. I don't have delete list option as it was system generated task list. Any thoughts on this...

Comment: It's possible you don't have access to the tasks due to your level of access - if you have access to Central Administration, grant yourself a "Full Control" user policy to the Web Application (Make sure you remove this afterwards - User Policy on Web Apps are something that should be kept as clean as possible), then check the list again. Deleting the list is a bad idea (Sorry - i misread your last comment), as you said, it's a system list and should be retained.

Comment: I am site collection administrator. I also tried looking by farm admin level nothing in workflow task list. Just speculating, Could it be some task sitting in outlook task list causing it? If it is possible which account should I look for this outlook task? I must thank you for your time and efforts you are putting in for helping me through.

Comment: You've definitely received an email from somewhere informing you that there is a task somewhere and it's overdue - What happens when you click the "Edit this task..." button at the top of the email? If you can open the task itself in SharePoint, then you can trace down which list it's come from - you won't be receiving overdue alerts from SharePoint unless there is an associated task.

Comment: Following error message comes when I click on edit task button.                    Microsoft Office Outlook

An error occurred while retrieving the workflow task details. This could be caused by not having connectivity to the server or because the task no longer exists. 
If this error persists, contact your system administrator.

Comment: Hmm, from the sounds of it, the tasks have automatically purged themselves from the system - are you still getting the emails, or has this issue resolved itself?

Comment: Not yet Still getting emails. Very frustrating. Please let me know if anything comes in to your mind. Really appreciate your efforts.